# How to send JMX metrics to statsD daemon?

Tags: jmx, statsd, jmxtrans

How to send JMX metrics to statsD daemon? I can see there are solutions where there are plugins to poll JMX metrics but I am looking more to push metrics to some Daemon which can aggregate as well as store it in some storage such as InfluxDB?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there are any push based solutions out there. I use [JmxTrans](https://github.com/jmxtrans/jmxtrans) for external JVM processes. It can write to a number of destinations using [writers](https://github.com/jmxtrans/jmxtrans/wiki/OutputWriters) using a JSON configuration.